# Issue with angular auto populating the create form when I click on the edit form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a simple phonebook app with CRUD functionality in Angular. I am having an issue where Angular's ng-model is auto populating my create form when I click on my edit button that has its own form for editing. How can I separate the two forms without losing functionality? [Picture of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL3Of.png) If the code is not readable, I have linked my project on github: [contacts_angular_practice](https://github.com/malissaromero/contacts_angular_practice/tree/master)

```
<-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="contactsApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Contacts</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/main.js"></script>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Contacts</h1>

  <!-- create functionality-->
  <div ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl" class="list">
    <div class="add">
      <a href="" ng-click="mainCtrl.toggleForm()">+ Add a New Contact</a>
      <form ng-show="mainCtrl.formIsVisible" ng-submit="mainCtrl.create()">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input placeholder="Enter Name" class="createInput" type="text" name="name" ng-model="mainCtrl.name">

        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input placeholder="Enter Phone Number" class="createInput" type="text" name="phoneNumber" ng-model="mainCtrl.phoneNumber">

        <button class="new">New Contact</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- edit, update and delete functionality -->
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="contact in mainCtrl.contacts">
      <!-- | orderBy:'-name': true -->

      <!-- show data -->
      <div ng-show=!editContact>
        <label ng-show="!editContact">{{contact.name}}</label>
        <label ng-show="!editContact">{{contact.phoneNumber}}
        </label>
      </div>

      <!-- form for editing -->
      <form ng-show="editContact">
        <input ng-model="mainCtrl.name" class="editing-label" type="text"/>

        <input ng-model="mainCtrl.phoneNumber" class="editing-label" type="text"/>
      </form>

        <!-- edit, save and delete buttons -->
      <div class="actions">
        <a href="" class="edit" ng-click="mainCtrl.edit($index); editContact = !editContact">Edit</a>
        <a href="" class="save" ng-click="mainCtrl.update($index); editContact = !editContact">Save</a>
        <a href="" class="delete" ng-click="mainCtrl.delete($index)">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>

<-- app.js -->
'use strict';

(function() {
  var app = angular.module('contactsApp', [
    'mainController'

  ])
})()

<-- main.js(controller) -->
(function() {
  angular.module("contactsApp", [])
  .controller("mainController", function() {

  this.contacts = [
    {"id": "0", "name":"Carson Daly", "phoneNumber":"000-000-0000"},
    {"id": "1", "name":"Britney Spears", "phoneNumber":"000-000-0000"},
    {"id": "2", "name":"Freddie Prince Jr", "phoneNumber":"000-000-0000"},
    {"id": "3", "name":"Halle Berry", "phoneNumber":"000-000-0000"},
    {"id": "4", "name":"Gary Oldman", "phoneNumber":"000-000-0000"},
    {"id": "5", "name":"Aaron Carter", "phoneNumber":"000-000-0000"}
  ]

  this.formIsVisible = false
  this.toggleForm = function() {
    console.log("toggleform")
    if(this.formIsVisible){
      this.formIsVisible = false
    }
    else {
      this.formIsVisible = true
    }
  }

  this.reset = function(){
    this.name = ""
    this.phoneNumber = ""
  }

  this.create = function() {
    console.log("clicked")
    this.contacts.unshift({
      name: this.name,
      phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber
    });
    this.reset()
  };

  this.edit = function(index) {
    var contact = this.contacts[index];
      this.name = contact.name;
      this.phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumber;
  };

  this.update = function(index) {
    var contact = this.contacts[index];
      contact.name = this.name;
      contact.phoneNumber = this.phoneNumber;
  };

  this.delete = function(index){
    console.log("whats up")
    console.log(index)
    this.contacts.splice(index, 1);
  };

});
})();
```

Comment: I think the trouble here is that both forms are effectively using the same Contact. This is at least partially because you have everything happening inside your "Main Controller". Could you create two controllers -- one for creating new Contacts and one for editing existing Contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer by installing ng-Inspector browser extension.

I immediately saw that I wrote two controllers on the line:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
```

I thought I was creating a shortcut. I changed the the line to:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
```

After that It worked great. I had to change my functions to reference $scope instead of this in the controller. I also had to change ng-models in the index.html file from mainCtrl.name to contact.name. After I made these changes it worked perfectly. The changes can be seen on my github link to the project: [contacts_angular_practice](https://github.com/malissaromero/contacts_angular_practice)